# tanh from Accelerate vs tanh in C

Tags: ios, c, accelerate-framework

I just saw that the Accelerate framework has this: 
I have a function that does a lot of tanh calculations.

void vvatanh ( double *, const double *, const int * );
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/#//apple_ref/c/func/vvatanh

Compared to tanh in C code, is this any faster? 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_tanh.htm

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself ?

Comment: @Ippier: If you don't measure it yourself, it demonstrates that you don't care about the answer. So go and measure it, then post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*NOTE: Your question and my original answer had some typos. To perform a tanh, you meant `vvtanh`, not `vvatanh` (or `vatanh` as I originally wrote). `vv` means "vector" (technically from the vForce library. `vvatanh` is the vector base **inverse** hyperbolic tangent.)*

First, the point that should be obvious: If `vvtanh` were universally faster/better than `tanh`, then `tanh` would simply be implemented as `vvtanh`. The fact that both exist strongly suggests that they have different purposes or trade-offs. As others have said, profiling is important, but profiling alone isn't always enough. You need to understand how the functions mean to be used, or else your profiling will tell you that Accelerate is shockingly slow and useless.

The vector functions in Accelerate are designed to efficiently work on large vectors (arrays) of numbers simultaneously. In order for them to be useful, you must structure you data correctly. Calling a vector function on a single value is generally going to be slower than the non-vector form, since the vector form necessarily has some kind of iteration logic inside of it. The compiler and standard libraries are always free to use the vector processor (and do); you should not imagine that Accelerate has access to any magical go-fast instructions that are not available elsewhere. The difference is the algorithm used, not the vector processor per se.

So, if you have a large group of numbers arranged in a C-array and need to compute `tanh` on them all at once, then `vvtanh` is likely a good tool and you should profile it. If nothing else, you may save the function-call overhead of iterating over `tanh` (provided it's not inlined).

If your problem is not structured that way, then you should try to redesign your data structures and algorithms so that the problem *can* be structured that way. Most use of vectorization is about getting your data in the right form, and then making a single function call.

If you can't structure you data that way, and you would be forced to call `vvtanh` many times, then it's almost certainly a lose, and the simpler `tanh` is going to be better.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, an array containing more than 16 floats is usually good enough to see a performance win for the array interfaces. For some really cheap functions, the crossover might be 64 and for some expensive functions it might be 8, but that is a good ballpark.  For just a few values, it is better to call the math library.     The C math library can be a bit more accurate, for example max error of 0.6 ulps vs. 3 ulps.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, if you're concerned about performance you need to experiment carefully.

However, there are some factors that impact performance:

1: Accelerate is a library of vector operations that are hardware accelerated on vector hardware if available.  The API takes a vector of operands and will gain some of its gains with careful instruction and cache scheduling.  If you're not performing a large number of operations, the cost of the function may start to dominate. If you're simply after a single operation, it's highly unlikely to be faster.

2: It's fair-game for a compiler to inline standard library functions using native instructions. Without looking at the assembly generated by the compiler it's hard to know whether it did or not.

3: There are a number of approximations that can be used to calculate `tanh()`. Their suitability depends hugely on the range of input values and the accuracy demanded by your application.  Accelerate may well be using such an approximation and not be as accurate as the std lib.